# I am having an error on react-multi-carousel

Tags: react-native, npm, react-multi-carousel

This is my code

```
import MultiCarousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import { ImageBackground, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from '../components/Styles';

const HomeScreen = props => {
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.carouselCategoryParent}>
                        <MultiCarousel responsive={responsive}>
                            <div>Item 1</div>
                            <div>Item 2</div>
                            <div>Item 3</div>
                            <div>Item 4</div>
                        </MultiCarousel>;
               </View>
        </View>
    );
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

This is the error I am getting on my code;

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at: 
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at HomeScreen.js:61)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at HomeScreen.js:46)
```

This is what i have tried so far, hoping to get some solutions

Comment: First, React is not defined here, you have to import it before using JSX, if that's imported but you didn't paste it here, you have to paste full code then. Second, there are no <div> component in react-native, you have to use <View> instead. And there is even error location in the error message ```in View (at HomeScreen.js:61)```, ```in View (at HomeScreen.js:46)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the ";" after the closing tag `</MultiCarousel>` and change `<div>` to `<View>`.
`<div>` is not a valid element in React Native.